# IOS ZXING parsing vcard result

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, zxing

I'm using ZXING on ios to decode qr codes.
i'm able getting the string result, if it's http i open the browser intent,
But if i'm scanning a vcard i'm getting this:

```
@"BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD"
```

Other apps parse the result to contact,
Does anyone know a class the can parse this vcard result to some kind of a dict or an ios contact object ?
Seems like parsing it on my own will be a huge effort and i also dont have the full docs to support all existing vcard versions.

I know zxing for android support the vcard parsing but for some reason can't find a ported code to Objective-C.

Comment: I didn't see such parsers, but I'm not sure they aren't exist at all. But anyway be ready to write your own one :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid vCard; remove the 2 first characters (@") and the last one (").

Maybe it's the QR Code you used? Here's one created using [Unitag](https://www.unitaglive.com/qrcode):

[image: here is a valid QR Code vCard created using Unitag.]

You can find the full RFC for vCards here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350